# How to isolate list elements that have been added n times?

Tags: python

I have the following code which takes a user input for the number of spaces along a road and *should* return a randomised list with a 1 representing a car and 0 nothing. This is then repeated across all road densities ranging from 0 to 1 and the distributions are randomised.

```
spacenum = int(input("Enter number of road spaces:"))
    i=0
    while i<= spacenum:
        a.append([1]*i)
        a.append([0]*(spacenum-(i)))
        random.shuffle(a)
        print (str(a).strip('],'))
        a.clear()
        i+=1
```

And this produces the following lists for n=3:

```
Enter number of road spaces:3
[[], [0, 0, 0]]
[[1], [0, 0]]
[[0], [1, 1]]
[[1, 1, 1], []]
```

What is happening is each chunk of 1's or 0's is sticking together as an element, which is not what I intended. How do I rewrite my code so that each 1's and 0's are evenly spread throughout each list. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be trying to extend a list by appending a list at the end. Use `a.extend()` instead.

Comment: Thanks very much! Its now doing what I want it to.